# VS code doesn't gray out unused JavaScript variables

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, unused-variables

As far as I know it seems this is the setting you enter in your `settings.json` to enable unused variables & imports that aren't used to appear grayed out.

```
"editor.showUnused": true,
```

I do get an underline and if you hover I get an underline and message on hover.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: It used to be grayed out for me, but suddenly it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @aviya.developer Check out my answer, hope this works for you...

Comment: So i honestly don't know when and why did the following happen: vscode has `@builtin` extensions. One of them is `typescript and javascript language features`. For some reason this extension was disabled globally for me. Enabled it and it works as it used to... That's 4 hours of work done....

Comment: @aviya.developer Sorry to hear that!!

Comment: at least it's working again :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In my `settings.json` apparently I commented that the following did the trick.

```
 "javascript.validate.enable": true,

/* this controls having your unused imports or variables to appear grey */
```

Comment: Hi, could you help? I've tried all the fixes here, and none work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77118036/vscode-is-not-graying-out-unused-variables

Comment: @LeonGaban Sorry for the late reply; Are you still stuck?

Comment: no problem anymore, I got it working

Answer (score 5):

*** builtin language features extension solution:**

*I am adding this just in case someone gets stuck like me. I had the same issue and the following was the problem.*

vscode has `@builtin` extensions. One of them is `typescript and javascript language features`. If it is disabled the features will not work. So just go to extension and search `@builtin` typescript and javacsrtipt language feature, click the cog icon and enable the extension.

Answer (score 3):

#### September 2020

For me, adding `"editor.showUnused": true,` in `settings.json` in the `.vscode` directory worked.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above solutions worked for me.
I needed to install the ESLint vscode extension (the one with over 25 million downloads)
then it started working again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `deno` extension was causing the problem. disabling it seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For JavaScript code, make sure you haven't accidentally disabled the `javascript.validate.enable` setting (it defaults to `true`).

If the variable is a global variable in a non-module file, then this is by design, since the global variable could be used in other files / non-module code, and there's no reliable way for static analysis to know whether that will happen or not (see [#189056](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/189056)).